# React app - Load selected array in Material UI Table not rendering checks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling, material-ui

So I have been working hard for days and searching on how to do this.  I have a Material UI table in my React App.  I want to load a table where if my user has entries in the selected array it will prerender the checks in the DOM.   The selected array is populated with the entries I want but  my table which uses a onClick I think needs an event to trigger the DOM to render the check.  This is relevant part of my table body.

```
<TableBody>
                            {this.props.competitorData.map(competitor => {
                                const isSelected = this.props.isSelected(competitor.key);
                                return (
                                    <TableRow
                                        hover
                                        onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(competitor)}
                                        role="checkbox"
                                        aria-checked={isSelected}
                                        tabIndex={-1}
                                        key={competitor.key}
                                        selected={isSelected}
                                    >
                                        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                            <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
                                        </TableCell>
```

I have a toggle that loads my table.  It fills the selected the array with the subset of data I want trigger in componentWillMount.  (it's 2 tables, tier1 and tier 2).

```
    componentWillMount() {
    this.renderChecks(this.props.team)
}

renderChecks(team) {
    const { selected1 } = this.state;
    const { selected2 } = this.state;
    let newSelected1 = [];
    let newSelected2 = [];

    team.map(teammate => {  
        if (teammate.tier === "1") {
            newSelected1 = newSelected1.concat(selected1, teammate.key)
        } else if (teammate.tier === "2") {
            newSelected2 = newSelected2.concat(selected2, teammate.key)
        }

        this.setState({ selected1: newSelected1 });
        this.setState({ selected2: newSelected2 });

    })      

}
```

Essentially I need a way to render isSelected based of another list that is the smaller list (team is a subset of competitorData) that has the same keys.  Ive tried so many things it's to many to list here.  Im looking for help on what to do to make this work because nothing has worked and Im not sure what direction I should be going on in at this point.  I've tried a lot of things that seem to cause instability in the render.  Essentially I've tried to make the isSelected more state based but setting and resetting that state with inline functions like

```
 {() => this.myFunctionThatUpdatesIsSelectedState(Key)}
```

These blow up in render.  Sometimes cause an ugly infinite loop.

***Update***

Based on @Eld0w post below this does render my subset of checks.

```
     checkKeys(val) {
        return this.props.team.some(teammate => {
            return val.key === teammate.competitorKey;
        });
}

getCompetitors = () => {
    const { competitorData, team } = this.props;
    return competitorData.map(
        value => ({
            value,
            isSelected: this.checkKeys(value)
        })
    )
}
```

Tables looks like this now.

```
                            <TableBody>
                            {this.getCompetitors().map(competitor => {
                                console.log('MYCOMPETITOR2::', competitor);
                                return (
                                    <TableRow
                                        hover
                                        onClick={event => this.props.handleClick(event, competitor.value)}
                                        role="checkbox"
                                        aria-checked={competitor.isSelected}
                                        tabIndex={-1}
                                        key={competitor.value.key}
                                        selected={competitor.isSelected}
                                    >
                                        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                            <Checkbox checked={competitor.isSelected} />
                                        </TableCell>
```

There is small issues I didn't see coming.  Now my table renders only the preselected checks since im not using my previous isSelected function which was:

```
 isSelected1 = key => this.state.selected1.indexOf(key) !== -1;
```

Basically i need to render the existing checks but maintain the standard isSelected function somewhere in the process as well.  If I think of something or  post anything about it I'll update here as well.   Further input is obviously welcome.

I think i need to load my team into my selected array then run my standard isSelected function.  But this is where I seem to run into trouble since that is state based. Render goes crazy on me.

***Final Update***

So it was late last night.  I just needed to change the criterion to make this whole thing work.  I load my team array in the local state selected array.  Then performed isSelected property check on my competitor.  Now it loads my preselected and the user can then edit selects in the table from that point.

Final Solution

Load the preselect team into the local selected state array.

```
    componentWillMount() {
    this.renderChecks(this.props.team);
}
```

I have tiered tables.  That is just some business logic (not important here).  teammate.competitorKey is the key I store that is same key as the larger table, which is competitorData.  I need that to get the compares to work.

```
renderChecks(team) {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    let newSelected = [];
    team.map(teammate => {
        if (teammate.tier === '1') {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, teammate.competitorKey)
            this.setState({ selected: newSelected });
        }
    })
}
```

getCompetitor can now just verify the value key exist in the array using includes

```
getCompetitors = () => {
    const { competitorData, team } = this.props;
    console.log('THISSTATESELECTED:::', this.state.selected)
    return competitorData.map(
        value => ({
            value,
            isSelected: this.state.selected.includes(value.key)
        })
    )
}
```

And Final Table looks like

```
                            <TableBody>
                            {this.getCompetitors().map(competitor => {
                                return (
                                    <TableRow
                                        hover
                                        onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, competitor.value)}
                                        role="checkbox"
                                        aria-checked={competitor.isSelected}
                                        tabIndex={-1}
                                        key={competitor.value.key}
                                        selected={competitor.isSelected}
                                    >
                                        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                            <Checkbox checked={competitor.isSelected} />
                                        </TableCell>
```

I know this is a lot of writing but is spent a lot of time trying to get all this working.  I hope it helps someone looking to do.  I will look into making this more redux worth and possibly going the reselect route to optimize but for now im going to enjoy a working table for a day.  Thank you again @Eld0w  !!

Comment: Can you make a test case that shows the problem? Start from here if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/nrkqqkq8mj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you want to add an `isSelected` props to your competitors array depending on another array's values. Avoid using state, it's only props combinations.

**The straightforward solution**

Instead of mapping directly your competitor's array, map on a function returning an array.

```
getCompetitors = () => {
  const { competitors, team } = this.props;
  return competitors.map(
    competitor => ({
      ...competitor,
      isSelected: // criterion
    })
  )
}
```

Basically, what this does is destructuring the object and adding a new property `isSelected` thanks to the spread operator `...` (ES6)

In your render then call `this.getCompetitors().map(competitor => ...)` instead of `this.props.competitors`.

**Optimize this solution**

You will want to use a plugin such as [`reselect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to avoid any useless render operation.

```
const competitorSelector = createSelector(
  props => props.competitors,
  props => props.team,
  (competitors, team) => competitors.map(
    competitor => ({
      ...competitor,
      isSelected: // criterion 
    })
  )
)
```

and then use it like this in your render :

```
this.competitorSelector(this.props)
```

You will also need to use `competitor.isSelected` instead of `isSelected` since the property is now part of your competitor's properties.

Comment: Great.  Let me digest this and I will get back to your response.  Thank you!!

Comment: So Team is my other Array, where am I using that in this solution?  I've been thinking this is probably a reselect situation all along and I have some selectors wired in other components but im am pretty new to selectors.  Still getting my head around it.  Either way, want to understand the straightforward here, then I'll move towards your Optimize.  So where is my second array come in this solution.  in the isSelected I would specify my team array keys there??

Comment: BTW, the func getCompetitors is getting type error saying it's not a function when I try to pass my Immutable list to it like so: {this.getCompetitors(this.props.competitorData)(competitor => {

Comment: And I tried:     {this.getCompetitors.map(this.props.competitorData)(competitor => {

Comment: Immutable has map with it so Im not sure why the type issue.  It mapped when doing it directly before, not sure why the type issue now

Comment: I corrected a few mistakes in my post and added how to pass the team props if that can help you - i'm just not sure about the criterion you are doing but you have all tools to compute a isSelected function taking both arrays as parameters and returning a boolean :) - pretty sure you could use Array.some() as it returns a boolean

Comment: yeah, this makes more sense.  Let me try this out.Thanks Alot!!

Comment: Thank man!  I gotta figure out how to load preselected and keep isSelected function intake now as well.  Maybe it's just late but im not exactly sure how thats gonna work but you answered my question here.  Thanks again! Accepted and upvoted.